# consuming web service dropping a specific node on return

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, soap

I have a .net web app that's hitting an external web service hosted by another company. The web service returns an xml object which I am capturing and parsing with an XmlSerializer.

This process works fine, every time. Only problem is, one very important node is always dropped from the return. I have hit their system via a simple HTTP post backdoor that they opened up for me for testing, and its there, so its definitely being generated. When I grab the xml from the web service, every other node except this one is present and accounted for.

The node's name is

```
<reference></reference>
```

... is this some sort of reserved word in .net that would cause it to be ignored? Has anyone else ever run into an issue like this, and maybe could give me a few common things to check first?

The node is not actually in the wsdl, but they generate it dynamically... there are a few other nodes like that, which DO come through the service with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question:

> The node is not actually in the wsdl

If it's not in the WSDL, then what exactly do you expect .NET to do about it? .NET is actually doing precisely the right thing - ignoring it!

"WSDL" stands for "Web Service ***Description*** Language". If they don't describe this element, then how can they expect anyone to consume it?

Comment: In most cases I would agree immediately. However there are other nodes that aren't present in the WSDL which ARE coming through the webservice. I know this because I've seen it in action and compared it against said WSDL. When I mentioned it to the external host, they said that theses are dynamically generated xml nodes that aren't supposed to be present in the WSDL. If you're saying its impossible, not sure how they are managing it?

Comment: What do you mean, "coming through the webservice"? That's nonsense. There are no properties in the proxy classes which did not come from the WSDL (and any included WSDL or XSD).

Comment: Relax with the nonsense, I'm not an expert at this, simply trying to explain myself. I have xml coming through their webservice or returned from or whatever nomenclature you like. They are claiming some of the nodes are "dynamically generated" and dont have to be in the wsdl. I agree that this seems like its impossible, so I'm asking for further clarification from them. I think they may mean that parameters of nodes are generated dynamically, not the nodes themselves.

Comment: You're right - you're not an expert. I am. My expert opinion is that it is "nonsense" to suppose that the proxy class contains properties which were generated for any reason other than that they are in the WSDL. Maybe you mean something different when you say these nodes are "coming through the service"? How are you accessing those nodes? You cannot be accessing them through properties.

Comment: I didnt write original code, trying to pick up the ball and run with it here. I have the web service as a service reference. I call a method, passing in a formatted xml string. The web service returns an xml response which I serialize with this:  Dim x As New XmlSerializer(GetType(ServiceAddRS))  Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter()
   x.Serialize(sw, serviceResponse), this response I'm capturing as a string. Everything that I'm expecting in the xml is there, except for one node which is also missing from the wsdl. That's probably the problem, I agree. They're telling me it doesnt have to be there

Comment: Ok, this is why you should show code! I had no idea you were passing XML around. I thought you were talking about a normal web service, where objects get serialized into XML. Please show some code.